# This context of function at top level vs function defined within an object

Tags: javascript

In the following code example:

```js
'use strict';
function hello(name) {
    console.log(this); 
}
hello('Annie');
// undefined

let o = {
    hello() {console.log(this);}
}
o.hello('Annie');
```

Why does a function have no `this` context when it's placed by itself, but it does when it is placed within an object?

Comment: In strict mode, top-level functions have no context. In non-strict mode the context is the `window` object.

Comment: What were you expecting the context to be for the top-level function?

Comment: I think it was decided that `this` isn't actually useful, or worse, the source of bugs, when a function is called "normally". Hence strict mode makes it so that `this` is `undefined`.